# Handling SetWindowsHookEx zero return value

Tags: c#, winapi, compact-framework, windows-ce, keyboard-hook

I have used in module this helper class: http://tinyurl.com/pb3vxw6 and I have following problem: SetWindowsHookEx always returns zero value.  As I mentioned this API function is not documented. Is this API function still supported in Win CE 6.0 devices? Should I use another API function? How can realize keyboard hooks in another way?

```
public void Start()
{
    if (hHook != 0)
    {
         // Unhook the previouse one
         this.Stop();
    }

    hookDeleg = new HookProc(HookProcedure);
    // in hHook returned zero value  
    hHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, hookDeleg, GetModuleHandle(null), 0);

    if (hHook == 0)
    {  // Exception throwed
       throw new SystemException("Failed acquiring of the hook.");
       // May be better?
       // Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());

    }
}
```

Comment: Undocumented == expected not to work.  A mouse hook can work if the [image was built properly](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/raffael/archive/2008/05/12/setwindowshookex-on-windows-mobile.aspx).

Comment: Does [QASetWindowsJournalHook](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/122754/Using-Input-Hooks-in-Windows-Mobile) work any better?

Comment: Your code can work on Windows CE 6.0/5.0 devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this program or DLL? You need dll to get keyboard hook working (and hook keyboard your dll). I should past hInstance instead GetModuleHandle(null). So when you hook keyboard windows actually calls that dll.

Answer (score 1):

You do not really need a DLL but undcoumented can mean not implemented.

http://www.hjgode.de/wp/2009/12/04/hooking-the-keyboard-message-queue-in-compact-framework-code/
 The code above worked on several devices.

What is GetLastError giving?